# Filter excel tables - Date formats

Tags: excel, vba, date, filter

I have a problem with filtering my table by dates. The Table is created via PowerQuery and the data type for the date values is set as "Date" in the table. I am trying to filter two columns containing date values, but the result is always blank.

I don't understand why, because if i perform the procedure manually, results are shown. The data type is also date. I've tried the following:

- Cdate()
- .Value2 (instead of .Value)

I've also checked that filtering strings for this table works fine. What is wrong with this?

```
Sub ExecuteFilters()
    
Dim Start_Date As Date
Dim End_date As Date
    
    Start_Date = CDate(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("VBA2").Range("F2").Value2)
    End_date = CDate(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("VBA2").Range("F3").Value2)
    
    
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Employee View").ListObjects("Employee_View_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & Start_Date
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Employee View").ListObjects("Employee_View_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, _
        Criteria1:="<=" & End_date

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `CLng(Start_Date)` - depending on your regional settings this is the solution.

Comment: Adding CLng(Start_Date) returns "Compile error: Syntax error". Why is this?

Comment: How do you use it? Like this: `Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(Start_Date)` ?

Comment: In the Immediate window type: `?ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("VBA2").Range("F2").Value2` and `?ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("VBA2").Range("F3").Value2` and see what they return.